# DATA foo TYPE ANY TABLE possible?

Tags: abap

I have the following problem: 
I'm testing many BAPI's and dont want to create a Table with the corosponding types for the rows, each time I call a new BAPI.

Is it possible to generate s.th. like a generic table like:

```
DATA foo TYPE ANY TABLE.
```

and use this to put it as the table parameter to get the result of the bapi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible - you can't declare variables using a generic type. However, you could try to determine the data type (e. g. using `RPY_FUNCTIONMODULE_*`) and then use [`CREATE DATA`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPCREATE_DATA_ITAB.htm) to create the table dynamically using a reference. Check the documentation of `CREATE DATA` for an example.